# DAX - How to return a value if date column falls between two periods?

Tags: datetime, dax

I have a datetime column in Dax that I want to split into the following groups by creating two new columns:

ColBefore would return a value of 1 if DateTimeCol falls between "07/14/2016 12:00:00AM" and "07/16/2016" 09:00:00AM" or else return value of 0

ColAfter would return a value of 1 if DateTimeCol falls between "07/16/2016 05:00:00PM" and "current time" or else return value of 0

Is this possible? I tried my best working with the `DATESBETWEEN` function but this did not allow for timestamp differential.

EDIT: Also if this is possible to do in SQL, I can work with that also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Power BI Desktop or Excel 2016 then you could use the datediff function. We can make use of the fact that its first parameter cannot be greater than the second:

```
ColBefore =
IF (
    IFERROR ( DATEDIFF ( "2016-04-14 12:00:00", [DateTimeCol], HOUR ), 0 ) = 0
        || IFERROR ( DATEDIFF ( [DateTimeCol], "2016-07-16 09:00:00", HOUR ), 0 ) = 0,
    0,
    1
)



ColAfter =
IF (
    IFERROR ( DATEDIFF ( "2016-04-16 05:00:00", [DateTimeCol], HOUR ), 0 ) = 0
        || IFERROR ( DATEDIFF ( [DateTimeCol], NOW(), HOUR ), 0 ) = 0,
    0,
    1
)
```